# How to wget a URL with HTTPS

Tags: curl, https, web-crawler, wget

I want to download "https://www.luisaviaroma.com/en-us/shop/home" with `wget`. I have tried `wget --no-cookie --no-check-certificate https://www.luisaviaroma.com/en-us/shop/home`. But it shows 
`HTTP request sent, awaiting response...` and no more response. How should I download the page with Wget?

Comment: I want to get the links of those products. But I can't find which `xhr/ajax` request is sent to get those item infomation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main difference here is the `user-agent` header. It looks like this host server declines Wget's `user-agent` header, so you send these headers just like your browsers does. I copied mine from Chrome:

```
wget https://www.luisaviaroma.com/en-us/shop/home --header="Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: It does work. I got the page. But the page downloaded with `wget`  is different to that downloaded by chrome(With `F12` and check `Sources` part).

Comment: I can't find which ajax/XHR request is sent  by "https://www.luisaviaroma.com/en-us/shop/home" to get those product items

Answer (score 0):

It seems this page at that URL is only accessible using [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2), for instance using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL):

```bash
curl -v 'https://www.luisaviaroma.com/en-us/shop/home' \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
```

which gives:

```
* Using HTTP/2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55d1310c6da0)
> GET /en-us/shop/home HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.luisaviaroma.com
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
< x-powered-by: ASP.NET
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< x-akamai-transformed: 9 - 0 pmb=mTOE,2
< expires: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 21:34:13 GMT
< cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< pragma: no-cache
< date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 21:34:13 GMT
```

But when forcing to HTTP 1.0 or HTTP 1.1,

```bash
curl -v 'https://www.luisaviaroma.com/en-us/shop/home' \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36' \
     --http1.0
```

it gives a different result:

```
> GET /en-us/shop/home HTTP/1.0
> Host: www.luisaviaroma.com
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: Apache
< ETag: "9c027fecce6719909433b8a37b2b403a:1493300815"
< Last-Modified: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 13:46:55 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 31186
< Content-Type: text/html
< Expires: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 21:36:19 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 21:36:19 GMT
< Connection: close
```

Using HTTP 1.0 or HTTP 1.1, we hit a different server serving a different page while using HTTP 2.0 it gives the expected page.

Using cURL which support HTTP 2.0 you will be able to download this page, for instance to save it under `homepage.html`:

```bash
curl 'https://www.luisaviaroma.com/en-us/shop/home' \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36' \
     -o homepage.html
```